# How to convert this codeigniter query to select for update

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, select

Lost update is a common MySQL issue and to solve it the select query should be edited to be a select for update query like this

```
select * from users where id = 1 FOR UPDATE
```

to prevent other users from working on the same row at the same time. I want to do this in codeigniter by editing this query to be a select for update query

```
public function get_row_data($id)
{

    $this->db->where('id',$id);

    $result = $this->db->get('users');

    if($result && $result->num_rows() > 0)
    {
        return $result->row();
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

I can use the above simple query but prefer if the model query could be converted.

Thanks

Comment: what? can you be more specific?

Comment: Your question isn't clear.

Answer (score 3):

It Seems You want to acquire Row Level Locking in Mysql
and codeigniter query builder doesn't allow to manipulate its method to produce custom sql query

```
$this->db->trans_begin();
$this->db->query('you query goes here');
// other task .....
if ($this->db->trans_status() === FALSE) {
    $this->db->trans_rollback();
} else {
    $this->db->trans_commit();
}
```